# Can a P55 chipset support 6GB as 2GBx3?

Tags: memory

Having purchased a P7P55D-E PRO board, I've gone and got me 6GB as 2GBx3 chips to use w/W7-64.
But I'm now confused as the manual there does not mention anything about a 3 chip configuration.

Hence the question, does the P55 chipset used on this motherboard support/recognize 6GB installed as 2GB x 3 chips?

Comment: If I were you, I would purchase a 4th stick if possible as RAM in a P55 board works best in Dual-Channel configuration (2 sticks instead of 1)

Comment: Posted a follow-up at http://superuser.com/questions/266504/how-much-of-a-performance-hit-using-asymmetrical-dual-channel-ram

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Intel diagram it only supports dual channel memory.

[image]

It may run on that configuration but may not be optimal since one memory module would not be running in dual channel mode. The Asus owners manual does not show using 3 modules, only 1 (single channel mode), 2, or 4 in dual channel mode.

Use the download tab and choose the OS then download the user manual.

> http://www.asus.com/product.aspx?P_ID=j02KziJq95KbCQNm&content=specifications

You'd be better off to go with 8GB - 2x4GB.

Comment: The manual came with the m/b (+: hence my question since I saw it did not mention an x3 configuration

Comment: Posted just in case.