# How much of a performance hit using asymmetrical dual channel RAM?

Tags: memory, performance, dual-channel

As a follow-up to my question [Can a P55 chipset support 6GB as 2GBx3?](https://superuser.com/questions/266357/can-a-p55-chipset-support-6gb-as-2gbx3); I understand there might be a performance hit using an odd-number of sticks.

My question therefore is - How much of a performance hit? Would it be perceptibly slower when running heavy process/memory hungry apps?

Comment: Performance seems to vary..http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual-channel_architecture#Performance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The motherboard will fall back to single channel mode.  See this TechSpot forum post: [Dual Channel with 3 sticks of RAM...](http://www.techspot.com/vb/topic39457.html)  This is why a 6GB configuration is typically 2x2GB, 2x1GB.

However, as per the Wikipedia article on [dual-channel architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual-channel_architecture), depending on your applications, you may or may not experience a significant performance difference.  Memory-heavy operations may be noticeably slower, but don't expect a very large difference.